# Name of old sci-fi show - man on a deserted planet, looking for a woman

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I am looking for the name of an old sci-fi show of which I saw only a part in the 90's (in USA). The part that I remember had this person (I thought it was some astronaut on a planet) walking through a city or a large open "strip mall", looking for a woman.

It seemed as is the man was on a planet that had previously had a large population of people but was now largely desolated, except for the buildings.

I think at some points during his search, the man had radio contact with the woman he was trying to find.

The show looked like it was a U.S. production, made in 70's (or in any case no later than early 80's), and in color. My impression was that this was a TV show rather than a movie.

What might have been the name of this show?

Comment: Until you said 70s, I thought it was season 1 of the Battlestar Galactica reboot.

Comment: thanks @Darren, did the Battlestar Galactica reboot have a scene like this and if so, when did it come out?

Comment: [2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica_(2004_TV_series)). The entire first season had a storyline where someone was walking around a now abandoned planet. Like this: http://www.battlestarlocations.com/uploads/8/1/0/8/8108293/9610421_orig.jpg

Comment: Can you describe either of the people?  Anything distinctive about the buildings?  (Assuming, of course, that it isn't BSG after all.)

Comment: thanks @Darren, the BSG buildings in that image look too "classy". The buildings in this TV show were like some 70's strip mall somewhere in USA but with probably more adverts (like Las Vegas style) around.

Comment: thanks @Steve-O, I will check to see if I can find images of scenes similar to those in this TV-show.

Comment: Unlikely, but check out Omega Man (1971): http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067525/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the third episode of the 80s mini-series [The Martian Chronicles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles_(miniseries))
  It has the man seeking woman in abandoned city theme, though they communicate by phone rather than radio.

Comment: thank you! I checked it on YouTube and it looks like the scenes starting at approximately at 12:27 [in this video](https://youtu.be/RYHj2HEjHFk?t=12m27s) match my memory.